# White screen on activity start

Tags: android

I'm not sure whether I'm understanding this properly but according to the life cycle of an activity onCreate is run first. As such, I've attempted to continue to run the activity from there by calling the onStart method.

Not sure whether that is even the correct thing to do. Regardless, the moment I start the activity (through a button in the main) all I see is a white screen. I've got setContentView but it doesn't appear that onCreate is even being run.

I also have the activity included in the manifest correctly and I'm sure of that.

Still new to all this and really unsure what to do though and would like some advice on the proper method of operating the activities methods. This community is fantastic and has helped me a lot in the past so thank you.

```
package example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback mPicture;
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

public void setContentView(int activity_camera) {}
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

SurfaceView camera_preview;
Button button_capture;

public CameraPreview(){
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    button_capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    camera_preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    onStart();
}

public void onStart(Context context, Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    super.onDestroy();
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public void onClick() {
    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
}

public SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
    return holder;
}

public void setHolder(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.holder = holder;
}
}
```

Comment: Try removing whole code and just put **onCreate()**. You will find out the problem.

Comment: Had you used an @Override annotation above your onStart() method, as you did with onCreate() the system would have warned you that you were not overriding from the super class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call the `onStart()` method. You just need to consider the onCreate() method. That's where you start your work.

Also you are calling the `setContentView(`) method wrong. You should call it like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
```

INSIDE your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Oh I apologise I didn't even notice this. I've already got it inside the onCreate() but it looks like it's also publicly declared which is silly. Turns out this was the problem and now everything works! Thank so much!

Answer (score 3):

**No!** Lifecycle methods (e.g. onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), etc) are called by the android system **directly**, don't ever explicitly call them yourself. Consider the activity lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to see how the system calls each method.

Furthermore, looking at your code, your own `onStart()` method isn't being called anywhere. Looking at the method signature:

```
public void onStart(Context context, Camera camera) {
```

You've just inadvertently overloaded the default `onStart()` method provided by android. Which doesn't really cause a problem, until you call the wrong method in your `onCreate()`, as shown here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    button_capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    camera_preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    onStart(); // <-- That is the activity's onStart, not yours!
}
```

which means that the whole block:

```
public void onStart(Context context, Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
```

is never getting called.

Either you dump all that code into `onCreate()` or name the method something different so you don't confuse yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This makes a lot of sense, I sort of knew this would be the answer. Once I've renamed the method to say startCameraPreview, what would be the appropriate way to start it? I'm having trouble understanding where the (Context context, Camera camera) fit into it.

Comment: @masteryupa Check out [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) on how to use the camera. I'd say you want to initiate the camera somewhere in `onResume()` and destroy it somewhere in `onPause()`.

Comment: Yeah this is the guide I got all of the code from. I feel like the problem now is that I have a SurfaceView but don't put anything from the camera on it.

Comment: @masteryupa I don't have much experience with the camera itself, so I can't really help you there. A quick flick of the documentation shows the `Camera` class has a few open() methods to create the actual camera instance. Just my opinion. but try placing the original `onStart()` code into `onCreate()` and put `mCamera.startPreview()` into `onResume()` to start only when the activity is ready (equivalently `mCamera.stopPreview()` in `onPause()`) .